# How can i use my files in php autoload using composer vendor in files example.controller.php

Tags: php, composer-php, spl-autoload-register

I  have a problem when i change my files for example example.controller.php. it not found, but when i change to exampleController.php it found using autoload composer vendor. if there a solution, thanks lot.

Comment: Controller file names may or may not be an issue. Showing your composer autoload section would help us a bit to help you.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. Also, please share how this problem is related to Composer itself

Answer (score 0):

Composer autoload psr-4 finds the corresponding file in the file system according to the namespace, so you need to ensure that the class name is consistent with the file name. If you can’t keep the same and want to use composer autoload, you can try other methods, such as files